# Mounting holes of Pi3 same as Parallella?

Tags: case, cluster

I am planning to buy a RaspberryPi 3 to get started on that, but wanted to prepare for the future by buying a stackable case. Now I also read about the Parallella and find the idea very interesting and was now wondering whether the mounting holes of the Parallella and the RaspberryPi3 are at the same places, so that you could stack them in the same case? Anybody an idea? I couldn't find any details on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working from the mechanical diagrams of the [Parallella](https://github.com/parallella/parallella-hw/blob/master/parallella-case/drawings/Mounting%20Plate.PDF) and [Pi 3](https://web.archive.org/web/20170421105820/https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/mechanical/RPI-3B-V1_2.pdf), there's a small chance you might be able to get a couple of screws through each board. As far as I can make out:

Parallella:

- 3.18mm hole diameter
- 80.01mm between hole centres (long side)
- 48.26mm between hole centres  (short side)

Pi 3:

- 2.75mm hole diameter
- 58mm between hole centres  (long side)
- 49mm between hole centres  (short side)

You *might*, with some delicate persuasion and filing, be able to *very very cautiously* get two screws through the boards on one matching short side. That would probably be enough to keep everything in place. The narrower gauge screws you'd need to use for the Pi mounting holes will mean that there's likely to be, at a minimum, some slop between screws and holes on the Parallella board.

Comment: Obvious Solution... Well, too bad, then I'll settle for the two case version I guess

Comment: That's the obvious solution indeed.  I'm buying the same setup, I will try modding the plexiglass to fit parallella. Let's see